# Prevent a table in overflow:auto div from shrinking

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm having a bit of an issue getting some stylesheet behavior that I want. I'm not even sure if it's possible. Basically I'm attempting to place a table with a variable number of cells with static cell width in a DIV with `overflow: auto`, and my goal is that when the tables width extends past the width of the container DIV that it becomes scrollable.

This isn't the case. The cells get shrunk together. A very basic representation (with inline styles for ease on this; not actually in the application haha) of the code:

```
<div style="width: 1000px; overflow-x: auto;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:400px;">
                This
            </td>
            <td style="width:400px;">
                Should
            </td>
            <td style="width:400px;">
                Scroll!
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Is there anyway I can do this with CSS, or am I going to have to go back to setting the width inline on a second div containing the table through calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works if you set the width on the `table` itself.

`<table style="width:1200px;">`

The `td` will always shrink to the necessary size, they won't push the table wider in that situation.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I wrote that in my post ;) I was just searching for a more elegant way of handling it through CSS.

Answer (score 3):

This should help

```html
<table style="width: max-content;">
```

Answer (score 0):

using CSS can done like below but make sure you use id or class for applying css if you have more then one table or div.

```
<style>
    div { width: 400px; overflow-x: auto; }
    table { width:1200px; }
    table td { width:400px; }
</style>


<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                This
            </td>
            <td>
                Should
            </td>
            <td>
                Scroll!
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```